# How to make atom-typescript write config out of tsconfig.json

Tags: typescript, atom-editor

I'm working in a team of 3 devs and we're writing a front-end client using `angular2` and `typescript`.

Two of us are using `WebStorm` and the third one is using `Atom` (personnal preference).

Problem is that `atom-typescript` needs some aditional configuration in `tsconfig.json`, and we don't want that since everytime the one dev using `Atom` will work on a projet, he will need to add

```
"atom": {
        "formatOnSave": true
 },
```

in `tsconfig.json`.

Is there any way to specify a different file for atom to parse some sonfig? I mean other IDE like `WebStorm` are using their own directory to store config in order to create an "IDE-independant" project by adding the config directory in `.gitignore` file.